# Moving member tensors with module.to() in PyTorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, gpu, pytorch, autoencoder

I am building a Variational Autoencoder (VAE) in PyTorch and have a problem writing device agnostic code. The Autoencoder is a child of `nn.Module` with an encoder and decoder network, which are too. All weights of the network can be moved from one device to another by calling `net.to(device)`.

The problem I have is with the reparametrization trick:

```
encoding = mu + noise * sigma
```

The noise is a tensor of the same size as `mu` and `sigma` and saved as a member variable of the autoencoder module. It is initialized in the constructor and resampled in-place each training step. I do it that way to avoid constructing a new noise tensor each step and pushing it to the desired device. Additionally, I want to fix the noise in the evaluation. Here is the code:

```
class VariationalGenerator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_nc, output_nc):
        super(VariationalGenerator, self).__init__()

        self.input_nc = input_nc
        self.output_nc = output_nc
        embedding_size = 128

        self._train_noise = torch.randn(batch_size, embedding_size)
        self._eval_noise = torch.randn(1, embedding_size)
        self.noise = self._train_noise

        # Create encoder
        self.encoder = Encoder(input_nc, embedding_size)
        # Create decoder
        self.decoder = Decoder(output_nc, embedding_size)

    def train(self, mode=True):
        super(VariationalGenerator, self).train(mode)
        self.noise = self._train_noise

    def eval(self):
        super(VariationalGenerator, self).eval()
        self.noise = self._eval_noise

    def forward(self, inputs):
        # Calculate parameters of embedding space
        mu, log_sigma = self.encoder.forward(inputs)
        # Resample noise if training
        if self.training:
            self.noise.normal_()
        # Reparametrize noise to embedding space
        inputs = mu + self.noise * torch.exp(0.5 * log_sigma)
        # Decode to image
        inputs = self.decoder(inputs)

        return inputs, mu, log_sigma
```

When I now move the autoencoder to the GPU with `net.to('cuda:0')` I get an error in forwarding because the noise tensor is not moved.

I don't want to add a device parameter to the constructor, because then it is still not possible to move it to another device later. I also tried to wrap the noise into `nn.Parameter` so that it is affected by `net.to()`, but that gives an error from the optimizer, as the noise is flagged as `requires_grad=False`.

Anyone has a solution to move all of the modules with `net.to()`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A better version of [tilman151's second approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54768936/344821) is probably to override `_apply`, rather than `to`. That way `net.cuda()`, `net.float()`, etc will all work as well, since those all call `_apply` rather than `to` (as can be seen in [the source](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/module.py), which is simpler than you might think):

```
def _apply(self, fn):
    super(VariationalGenerator, self)._apply(fn)
    self._train_noise = fn(self._train_noise)
    self._eval_noise = fn(self._eval_noise)
    return self
```

Comment: `_apply` method seems to be intentionally kept by the developer for not overriding. Rather, i would suggest having it register as a buffer with `persistent=False` arg as this will keep it away from the state_dict. Isn't this a more stable way ?

Comment: @lamo_738 Yes, I don’t think non-persistent buffers existed at the time of this answer, but that seems to be the best option now.

Comment: I have a list of Sequential objects that I want to move to the GPU. When doing that, I have the following error within the `_apply` function: `AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'is_floating_point'`

Comment: I think this doesn’t work anymore with pytorch 2.0.0 (the argument `fn`, which is defined as `convert` in `Module.to` cannot take a device as a parameter

Answer (score 8):

After some more trial and error I found two methods:

1. Use Buffers: By replacing `self._train_noise = torch.randn(batch_size, embedding_size)` with `self.register_buffer('_train_noise', torch.randn(batch_size, embedding_size)` the noise tensor is added to the module as a buffer. This lets `net.to(device)` affect it, too. Additionally the tensor is now part of the state_dict.
2. Override `net.to(device)`: Using this the noise stays out of the state_dict.

   ```
   def to(device):
       new_self = super(VariationalGenerator, self).to(device)
       new_self._train_noise = new_self._train_noise.to(device)
       new_self._eval_noise = new_self._eval_noise.to(device)

       return new_self
   ```

Comment: Approach 2 would probably be better by overriding `_apply` rather than just `to`; then `.cuda()`, etc all work too. ([my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57208704/344821))

Answer (score 2):

By using this you may apply the same arguments to your tensors and the module

```
def to(self, **kwargs):
    module = super(VariationalGenerator, self).to(**kwargs)
    module._train_noise = self._train_noise.to(**kwargs)
    module._eval_noise = self._eval_noise.to(**kwargs)

    return module
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
```

Now for both the model and every tensor you use

```
net.to(device)
input = input.to(device)
```

Comment: This was not the problem. The issue is that the noise tensor is not moved together with the weights when `net.to(device)` is used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`nn.Module`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html) buffers and parameters - both are considered when calling `.to(device)` and moved to the `device`.
Parameters are being updated by optimizer (so they need `requires_grad=True`), buffers are not.

So in your case, I'd write constructor as:

```py
    def __init__(self, input_nc, output_nc):
        super(VariationalGenerator, self).__init__()

        self.input_nc = input_nc
        self.output_nc = output_nc
        embedding_size = 128

        # --- CHANGED LINES ---
        self.register_buffer('_train_noise', torch.randn(batch_size, embedding_size))
        self.register_buffer('_eval_noise', torch.randn(1, embedding_size))
        # --- CHANGED LINES ---

        self.noise = self._train_noise

        # Create encoder
        self.encoder = Encoder(input_nc, embedding_size)
        # Create decoder
        self.decoder = Decoder(output_nc, embedding_size)
```