# How to get the device type of a pytorch module conveniently?

Tags: python, gpu, pytorch

I have to stack some my own layers on different kinds of pytorch models with different devices.

E.g. **A** is a **cuda** model and **B** is a **cpu** model (but I don't know it before I get the device type). Then the new models are **C** and **D** respectively, where

```py
class NewModule(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, base):
        super(NewModule, self).__init__()
        self.base = base
        self.extra = my_layer() # e.g. torch.nn.Linear()

    def forward(self,x):
        y = self.base(x)
        z = self.extra(y)
        return z

...

C = NewModule(A) # cuda
D = NewModule(B) # cpu
```

However I must move `base` and `extra` to the **same** device, i.e. `base` and `extra` of C are **cuda** models and D's are **cpu** models. So I tried this `__inin__`:

```py
def __init__(self, base):
    super(NewModule, self).__init__()
    self.base = base
    self.extra = my_layer().to(base.device)
```

Unfortunately, there's no attribute `device` in `torch.nn.Module`(raise `AttributeError`).

What should I do to get the device type of `base`? Or any other method to make `base` and `extra` to be on the same device automaticly even the structure of `base` is unspecific?

Comment: try `torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")` or the device form the set of parameters `device = next(mdl.parameters()).device`.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

This question has been asked many times ([1](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/7460), [2](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/12135)). Quoting the reply from a PyTorch developer:

`That’s not possible. Modules can hold parameters of different types on different devices, and so it’s not always possible to unambiguously determine the device.`

The recommended workflow ([as described on PyTorch blog](https://pytorch.org/blog/pytorch-0_4_0-migration-guide/#writing-device-agnostic-code)) is to create the `device` object separately and use that everywhere. Copy-pasting the example from the blog here:

```
# at beginning of the script
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

...

# then whenever you get a new Tensor or Module
# this won't copy if they are already on the desired device
input = data.to(device)
model = MyModule(...).to(device)
```

Do note that there is nothing stopping you from adding a `.device` property to the models.

As mentioned by Kani (in the comments), if the all the parameters in the model are on the same device, one could use `next(model.parameters()).device`.

Comment: Many thanks. I found the answer from your reference. Just use `next(model.parameters()).device`.

Comment: the next(_) trick only works if the model actually has parameters though, otherwise see Duane’s answer

Answer (score 36):

My solution, works in 99% of cases.

```
class Net(nn.Module):
  def __init__()
    super().__init__()
    self.dummy_param = nn.Parameter(torch.empty(0))

  def forward(x):
    device = self.dummy_param.device
    ... etc
```

Thereafter, the dummy_param will always have the same device as the module Net, so you can get it anytime you want. eg:

```
net = Net()
net.dummy_param.device

'cpu'

net = net.to('cuda')
net.dummy_param.device

'cuda:0'
```

Comment: Nice workaround, I think the design choice to allow different devices in one module was very questionable and I will pretty much never use it. So this will essentially just work for me.

Comment: This should be the answer. works great inside of forward, but does not required any change in function.

Comment: This works great. Besides, if you're using DataParallel, you will need to add `.module` suffix to the nnet object to access the `dummy` param: `nnet.module.dummy_param.device`

Answer (score 11):

@Duane's answer creates a parameter in the model (despite being a small tensor).

I think this answer is slightly more **pythonic** and **elegant**:

```
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.device = torch.device('cpu') # device parameter not defined by default for modules

    def _apply(self, fn):
        # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54706146/moving-member-tensors-with-module-to-in-pytorch
        # override apply by moving the attribute device of the class object as well.
        # This allows to directly know where the class is when creating new attribute for the class object.
        super()._apply(fn)
        self.device = fn(self.device)
        return self
```

`net.cuda()`, `net.float()`, etc will all work as well, since those all call `_apply` rather than `to` (as can be seen in [the source](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/module.py)).

An alternative solution from the comment of @Kani (accepted answer) is also very elegant:

```
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Constructor for Neural Network.
        """
        super().__init__()

    @property
    def device(self):
        return next(self.parameters()).device
```

You access the device through `model.device` as for parameters. This solution does not work when you have no parameter inside the model.

Comment: what happens when the function passed as an argument in "apply" does not take a "device" as parameter ? This never happens ?

Comment: `apply` is a private function which you should not call, and it takes as a parameter a function which itself take one input, the device :) so no, it is guaranteed to succeed.

Comment: Looking at the source code, I thing the function parameter of apply can also take other things, like dtype, or another tensor, when you call .to with a dtype or another tensor such as to copy its device/dtype. I may be wrong

Comment: oh yes you are right, I should have phrased it differently. What I had in mind is that `super` ensures you keep the expected behaviour, and applying on the device 
 `self.device = fn(self.device)`
should work, thanks to the fact we override `_apply` and not `apply`.